# How to authenticate Facebook User after receiving response.status === 'connected'?

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way but I have a website that allows facebook login.

1. If the user has already registered on my website
2. and is logged into facebook but not logged into my site
3. when visiting the login page i check for their facebook login status and get `response.status === 'connected'` via-

   ```
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) 
   {
       if (response.status === 'connected') 
       {
           var s = JSON.stringify(response.authResponse);
           LogMeIn(s, function(response) 
           {
               HandleAjaxError(response, function(msg)
               {
                   window.location = '/_/';  
               });
           });
       }
    }
   ```
4. I then want to pass their authResponse object to the server and confirm that this userid works with this token before I log them in as this user

I have read to simply grab the json contents of -

> https://graph.facebook.com/{userID}?access_token={accessToken}

and if it does not return an error then it is good! But when testing this method I noticed that the same access_token worked for two different user ids (meaning it did not return an error for the userid that was not logged in on my computer). Instead it returned the facebook user object with name , location etc.

This really surprised me, as I expected the `access_token` to `work only with a single user` id.

In an effort to prevent someone from simply changing the user id before continuing the script I need to authenticate via server side. What is a way to accomplish this?

Proof, go to these links to see profile information

My profile-

> https://graph.facebook.com/1233822590?access_token=CAACCBJJZBgjABAOGmvmsou8gMYGulLHTgAr5ZCHZAU7pKEp0cMAeX8r4qHLpiVuZCOT1v0ulMZAxX5YfLJkcZBr9l6qJQoPxWS5Fs5ndohDnH6ZAPPfZCZCTQtwWgAZAg6I1PAOIpdtCc0OUaMmBZAvGiMm9gQhmNXRbocZD

Another userid with same access_token-

> https://graph.facebook.com/100000116781159?access_token=CAACCBJJZBgjABAOGmvmsou8gMYGulLHTgAr5ZCHZAU7pKEp0cMAeX8r4qHLpiVuZCOT1v0ulMZAxX5YfLJkcZBr9l6qJQoPxWS5Fs5ndohDnH6ZAPPfZCZCTQtwWgAZAg6I1PAOIpdtCc0OUaMmBZAvGiMm9gQhmNXRbocZD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to be surprised. You can fetch the basic details of any user of the facebook using the access token of any user of the facebook.. So this isnt really good way to validate the token. Moreover, that confirmation of token part isnt required.

If you want the authorization through server side go through.[this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/) link